# Animate previous and next slides at the same time as main slide - cycle2

Tags: javascript, jquery, cycle2

As usual, apologies if this has already been answered but I found it very difficult to exactly describe what I am trying to do in a search query.

I am essentially trying to recreate the slide show here: http://www.aucklanddj.co.nz/weddings

Although I am using the jQuery cycle2 plugin. My main problem is getting the previous image and after image to show as well as the main image and then animate with them. Is this easily possible with cycle2?

This is currently what I have:

```
<div class="slide-container cycle-slideshow" 
    data-cycle-fx="scrollHorz"
    data-cycle-timeout="3000"
    data-cycle-speed="700"
    data-cycle-caption-plugin="caption2"
    data-hide-non-active="false">
        <img src="images/1.jpg" class="img-responsive pull-left" data-cycle-title="Spring" data-cycle-desc="Sonnenberg Gardens" />
        <img src="images/2.jpg" class="img-responsive pull-left" data-cycle-title="Redwoods" data-cycle-desc="Muir Woods National Monument" />
        <img src="images/3.jpg" class="img-responsive pull-left" data-cycle-title="Angel Island" data-cycle-desc="San Franscisco Bay" />
</div>
```

I was hoping the hide-non-active attribute would work but it doesnt animate the previous or next images.

Any help is greatly appreciated...even if you can suggest another jQuery plugin (or any other javascript solution) that may be better for what I am trying to do.

Thanks in Advance!

Matt

Comment: that site seems to be using http://bxslider.com/

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for what they were using but couldnt seem to find it...I'll look into it...

Comment: For anyone else looking for a similar solution i managed to solve it using bxSlider. I posted my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31000292/width-not-being-respected-in-bxslider